# Parsing timezone in format of "-xx:00"

Tags: python, timezone

I have a IP geolocation service that returns the users estimated timezone in the format of `-08:00`

At first I tried to dump this number into Pytz, but that doesn't work.  (I realize now that was a stupid idea.)

So how might I parse this number into a tzinfo object?

Comment: It's not a full time string, just the timezone in the above format.

Comment: related: [Get Timezone from City in Python/Django](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16505501/4279)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An offset is not enough to define a timezone, e.g., it ignores DST and other changes to the time in the area.

To get a limited tzinfo object you could use `pytz.FixedOffset(-8*60)`.