# Get Timezone from City in Python/Django

Tags: python, django, timezone

Using `pytz`, I am able to get a list of timezones like so:

```
>>> from pytz import country_timezones
>>> print(' '.join(country_timezones('ch')))
Europe/Zurich
>>> print(' '.join(country_timezones('CH')))
Europe/Zurich
```

Given that I am getting both Country and City fields from the user, how can I go about determining the timezone for the city?

Comment: You mean you want to search the timezone database for a specific city and get its timezone? Or do you just want the timezone of (in this case) `Europe/Zurich`?

Comment: I want to search the timezone database for a specific city and get its timezone

Comment: related: [How to get a time zone from a location using latitude and longitude coordinates?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16086962/4279)

Answer (score 34):

`pytz` is a wrapper around IANA Time Zone Database (Olson database). It does not contain data to map an arbitrary city in the world to the timezone it is in.

You might need a geocoder such as [`geopy`](https://github.com/geopy/geopy) that can translate a place (e.g., a city name) to its coordinates (latitude, longitude) using various web-services:

```
from geopy import geocoders # pip install geopy

g = geocoders.GoogleV3()
place, (lat, lng) = g.geocode('Singapore')
# -> (u'Singapore', (1.352083, 103.819836))
```

Given city's latitude, longitude, it is possible to find its timezone using [tz_world, an efele.net/tz map / a shapefile of the TZ timezones of the world](http://efele.net/maps/tz/world/) e.g., via [postgis timezone db](https://gist.github.com/zed/5566939) or [`pytzwhere`](https://github.com/pegler/pytzwhere):

```
import tzwhere

w = tzwhere()
print w.tzNameAt(1.352083, 103.819836)
# -> Asia/Singapore
```

There are also web-services that allow to convert (latitude, longitude) into a timezone e.g., [askgeo](http://askgeo.com/), [geonames](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#timezone), see [Timezone lookup from latitude longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41504/4279).

As [@dashesy pointed out in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16505501/get-timezone-from-city-in-python-django#comment46203751_16519004), `geopy` also can find timezone (since 1.2):

```
timezone = g.timezone((lat, lng)) # return pytz timezone object
# -> <DstTzInfo 'Asia/Singapore' LMT+6:55:00 STD>
```

[GeoNames also provides offline data](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/) that allows to get city's timezone directly from its name e.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import datetime
from urllib   import urlretrieve
from urlparse import urljoin
from zipfile  import ZipFile

import pytz # pip install pytz

geonames_url = 'http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/'
basename = 'cities15000' # all cities with a population > 15000 or capitals
filename = basename + '.zip'

# get file
if not os.path.exists(filename):
    urlretrieve(urljoin(geonames_url, filename), filename)

# parse it
city2tz = defaultdict(set)
with ZipFile(filename) as zf, zf.open(basename + '.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        fields = line.split(b'\t')
        if fields: # geoname table http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/
            name, asciiname, alternatenames = fields[1:4]
            timezone = fields[-2].decode('utf-8').strip()
            if timezone:
                for city in [name, asciiname] + alternatenames.split(b','):
                    city = city.decode('utf-8').strip()
                    if city:
                        city2tz[city].add(timezone)

print("Number of available city names (with aliases): %d" % len(city2tz))

#
n = sum((len(timezones) > 1) for city, timezones in city2tz.iteritems())
print("")
print("Find number of ambigious city names\n "
      "(that have more than one associated timezone): %d" % n)

#
fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z'
city = "Zurich"
for tzname in city2tz[city]:
    now = datetime.now(pytz.timezone(tzname))
    print("")
    print("%s is in %s timezone" % (city, tzname))
    print("Current time in %s is %s" % (city, now.strftime(fmt)))
```

#### Output

```
Number of available city names (with aliases): 112682

Find number of ambigious city names
 (that have more than one associated timezone): 2318

Zurich is in Europe/Zurich timezone
Current time in Zurich is 2013-05-13 11:36:33 CEST+0200
```

Comment: I think some time has passed, it seems now `geopy` itself can find timezone: `g.timezone(g.geocode('Singapore').point)`

Comment: @dashesy yes, it is now like other already mentioned online services in the answer. [`.timezone()` method is available for 6 months now](https://github.com/geopy/geopy/commit/b524a7a91cd81d64402829a1332e68154267c91a)

Comment: the only downside of offline data it takes good amount of storage space , and for those using hobby-dev or free tier of amazon this might  not work, even the max redis memory available for free is 30MB on redis cloud

Comment: here's a fully python 3 version on colab https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1-QL_qQVfFGGZ4_0xk6912VusOvgqw4_c

Comment: This no longer works out of the box. Google now asks you to create an account before being able to use the API

Answer (score 3):

there have been a lot of possible solutions proposed here and they're all a bit tedious to set up.

To make things quicker for the next person with this problem, I took the one from Will Charlton and made a quick python library out of it: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/whenareyou

```
from whenareyou import whenareyou
tz = whenareyou('Hamburg')
tz.localize(datetime(2002, 10, 27, 6, 0, 0))
```

Gets you `datetime.datetime(2002, 10, 27, 6, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Berlin' CET+1:00:00 STD>)`
.

This gets you a pytz object (`tz` in the example) so you can use it pythonicly.

- It uses the google API
- Leaves daylight savings calculation to pytz, only one call per city, rest happens offline
- LRU caches the requests so you shouldn't hit the API limit easily
- Should also work with any address or anything google maps understands

Comment: This looks like a quite interesting module, but when I try it today it returns error.  I was just using your example from README file.
     50     latlong = cached_json_get(
     51         LONG_LAT_URL.format(quote_plus(address))
---> 52     )['results'][0]['geometry']['location']
     53 
     54     return get_tz(latlong['lat'], latlong['lng'])

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Looks like I need to purchase google premium plan to have access to gmap data!

Comment: @LasseSchuirmann Even your example gave me the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dateutil'` if I install `python-dateutil` it gives me `UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 2098: character maps to <undefined>`I really liked the idea of your program but sadly it seems to not work.

Comment: @BenjaminK hey, sorry this was several years ago :/ I don't get your error, however it seems that the google API by now doesn't allow anonymous requests anymore.

If you're looking to fix it, please check out https://github.com/aerupt/whenareyou , I'll be available to review any changes and perform a release if needed.

Comment: @BenjaminK try the latest version from git, I just merged something that could help you. (I haven't tested it thoroughly, I don't have much time for open source stuff these days :/)

Comment: I received error: `ImportError: cannot import name '_normalize_host' from 'requests.packages.urllib3.util.url'`

Answer (score 3):

The idea is to find lat/long coordinates for given city (or state) with one of [geopy](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)'s geocoders, and get the appropriate time zone from the geocoder. Ex:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
from geopy import geocoders

# get the location by using one of the geocoders.
# GeoNames has a free option.
gn = geopy.geocoders.GeoNames(username='your-account-name')    
loc = gn.geocode("California, USA")

# some geocoders can obtain the time zone directly.
# note: the geopy.timezone object contains a pytz timezone.
loc_tz = gn.reverse_timezone(loc.point)

# EXAMPLE: localize a datetime object
dt_UTC = datetime(2020, 11, 27, 12, 0, 0, tzinfo=timezone.utc)
dt_tz = dt_UTC.astimezone(loc_tz.pytz_timezone)
print(dt_tz, repr(dt_tz))   
# 2020-11-27 04:00:00-08:00 
# datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 27, 4, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/Los_Angeles' PST-1 day, 16:00:00 STD>)
```

If the geocoder doesn't yield a time zone, you can use [timezonefinder](https://github.com/MrMinimal64/timezonefinder) to attribute a time zone to given lat/long coordinates.

Comment: from what I gather, `timezonefinder` works only with lats and longs. and geopy is down(as on Jul-1, 2PM IST), so haven't been able to register for a username. does anyone has an alternative? thanks.

Comment: @NaveenKumar: `GeoNames` webservice is working as far as I can tell; not sure about other geocoders though.

Comment: yes, it may be working, but i don't have an username to use. i get HTTP error when i try some dummy user name and geopy's website is down for me to be able to create an username.

Comment: @NaveenKumar:`geopy` is just the package; see [Geopy Is Not a Service](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#geopy-is-not-a-service). You'll need an account for a certain geocoding service.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're going to need to manually search the timezone database for the city you're looking for:

```
from pytz import country_timezones, timezone

def find_city(query):
    for country, cities in country_timezones.items():
        for city in cities:
            if query in city:
                yield timezone(city)

for tz in find_city('Zurich'):
    print(tz)
```

(that's just a quick-and-dirty solution, it for instance doesn't try to match only the city-part of a timezone – try searching for `Europe`, it does substring matches, doesn't search case-insensitive, etc.)

Comment: it doesn't work for most cities. Number of cities is much larger than number of timezones.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian OP wrote *"I want to search the timezone database for a specific city"*, so I limited my solution to cities in the timezone database provided by `pytz`.

Comment: OP wrote *"Given that I am getting both Country and City fields from the user, how can I go about determining the timezone for the city?"* How likely do you think a user gives the city name that is also a part of a timezone name?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian hence my question in the comments: *"You mean you want to search the timezone database...?"*.

Answer (score 1):

There is not trivial way of doing this, which is unfortunate.
Geonames records a list of every city, along with its time zone name.
This would be a god pick, but you will have to parse and build your own database around this, so you can easily find at any moment the time zone from a country/city pair.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving this with a couple Google API calls using `requests` and parsing through the JSON. I was able to do it without API keys because I'm never going to hit their usage limits.

https://gist.github.com/willcharlton/b055885e249a902402fc

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

this isnt upt to date. The best answer I found so far is

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
from timezonefinder import TimezoneFinder

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="anyName")
tf = TimezoneFinder()

coords = geolocator.gecode("Dallas, Texas")
tf = TimezoneFinder()
```

timezone = tf.timezone_at(lng=coords.longitude, lat=coords.latitude)
more details [here](https://koalatea.io/timezone-from-location/)

Answer (score -1):

@robertklep's approach probably works.

But here's another possible approach using `astral` - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/astral/0.5

```
>>> import datetime
>>> from astral import Astral

>>> city_name = 'London'  # assuming we retrieve this from user input

>>> a = Astral()
>>> a.solar_depression = 'civil'

>>> city = a[city_name]   # creates the city object given the city name above

>>> print('Information for %s/%s\n' % (city_name, city.country))
Information for London/England

>>> timezone = city.timezone
>>> print('Timezone: %s' % timezone)
Timezone: Europe/London
```

Comment: it should work by the list of supported cities is very small.

Comment: a lot of cities are not found there ... London is easy, but other cities are simply not listed there ..