# Is there any API for converting Address to Timezone offset

Tags: timezone, geocode

Is there a API available for converting Address to Timezone?

I have an idea of using Google GEOCODE API for converting Address to LAt long and then Timezone api to convert it into timezone.

Is this is a viable option? Has anyone done this in past?

Do we have any other options?

Comment: related: [Get  timezone from city in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16505501/get-timezone-from-city-in-python-django/16519004#16519004)

Answer (score 2):

There's always askgeo.com.  They do exactly what you are looking for.

Also, this question was previously answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504/timezone-lookup-from-latitude-longitude)

Answer (score 1):

[SmartyStreets](http://smartystreets.com) will return lat/long and time zone data for United States addresses, all in one step. You can do this via [API](http://smartystreets.com/products/liveaddress-api) or a [list upload](http://smartystreets.com/products/liveaddress-lists). Just keep in mind that time zone data can change, so you would need to update your data every once in a while to keep up with those changes (if you're planning on keeping some sort of database, etc.)

Another thing to be aware of is Daylight Savings Time observance, which SmartyStreets also indicates in its returned data. You can see a full list of our output fields [here](https://smartystreets.com/docs/address#fields).

(Disclosure: I work at SmartyStreets)

Update - 11 Jan 2016: SmartyStreets now processes [international addresses](https://smartystreets.com/docs/international).

Comment: Thanks Michelle. Good to know. But we have many non us users as well. so we need some global solution.

Comment: @sushilkumar a global solution is now available. Answer updated.

Comment: Current limit on Free Plan appears to be "250 free lookups every month".