# How to find the local datetime from a GMT datetime + Country+State or Country+City

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset, pytz

I have a GMT datetime:

```
import datetime, pytz
d = datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 27, 12, 0, 0)
```

Given a "country+sate" or "country+city" pair (when state is not available), or even better, with an [ISO 3166 two-part code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166#Parts) or a [`cityId`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/geoid) like this:

```
#case 1
country, state = 'US', 'CA'
#case 2
country, city = 'RU', 'Nowosibirsk'   # here no information of "State" is given
#case 3
iso = 'FR-ARA'  # France, Region Auvergne-Rhone-Alpes
#case 4
cityId = '1003854'       # Germany, Berlin, dataset here: https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/geo/geotargets-2020-11-18.csv
```

how to find the local timezone, and get the local datetime?

I know `pytz` can be useful, but obviously not all cities are listed in it (and even if it's the case, the spelling can vary, [see here](https://gist.github.com/heyalexej/8bf688fd67d7199be4a1682b3eec7568#file-pytz-time-zones-py-L298) for the city I mentioned on case #2).

**What are usual solutions for this timezone problem?**

Comment: pytz lists IANA time zone names, not cities. And with Python 3.9, you have a standard lib module for that, zoneinfo. By the way, your "GMT time" as you show it is a naive datetime object, thus local time. You need to set tzinfo to UTC first.

Comment: related: [get-timezone-from-city-in-python-django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16505501/get-timezone-from-city-in-python-django)

Comment: Country+State is not enough info, as several US states have more than one time zone.  Country+City is also not enough info, as many city names are duplicated at the country level (ex: [Springfield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Springfield)).  You will need, at minimum, City, State, *and* Country.  Then you can geolocate for lat/lon, then you can get a time zone from that.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint I think you can post this as an answer, that's the way to go. PS: are there really US states with 2 different hours at the same time *inside* a single state? Would you have an example?

Comment: Yes.  Many.  See the image in the duplicate I just closed this under.  (close enough dup, same answer).